# Bookmarks permission for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, permissions

I currently looking to build a Google Chrome Extension that fetches bookmarks from the the browser and sent them to server from synchronization perspective,but it seem to always complain me of "**`permission error`**" for the "**`API method`**" used in "`background.html`", even though I have set the necessary permission in "**`manifest.json`**"

Here what `my manifest.json` look like

```
{
  "name" : "Sync BookMark",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "content_script" : {
    "css"       : ["bookmark.css"],
    "js"        : ["js/jquery.js","js/bookmark.js"]

  },
  "browser_action"  :  {
    "default_icon"  :  "images/bookmark.png",    
    "default_title" :  "Syn Bookmark",
    "default_popup" :  "bookmark.html"
  },  
  "permission" : [ 
    "bookmarks",
    "management",
    "unlimitedStorage"

  ]
}
```

And Here my **background.html** code

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarks) {
  printBookmarks(bookmarks);
});

function printBookmarks(bookmarks) {
  bookmarks.forEach(function(bookmark) {
    console.debug(bookmark.id + ' - ' + bookmark.title + ' - ' + bookmark.url);
    if (bookmark.children)
      printBookmark(bookmark.children);
  });
}
```

// The above code is used from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812622/how-do-i-get-google-chromes-root-bookmarks-folder)

Now if try to debug the above code in the Chrome developer console 
It return a **error** of `permission of the API methods used.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it I just miss an 's' in permission i.e "permission" instead of "permissions"